# How enable PHPMailer to write complete persistent log?

Tags: emails, debugging

I am using the [PHPMailer module](http://drupal.org/project/phpmailer) to send emails to a user group (role) by a poormanscron-job.

I can see errors in my "**recent log entry**" view in the backend but I cannot get a **persistant log** with all log entries (I set the phpmailer settings to INFO or DEBUG level in the backend) somewhere.

I would like to check afterwards, **who got the email** and **if there were dropped mails** without errors (if that is possible).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what Drupal version you are on. But the [Maillog / Mail Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) module might be handy here. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> ... provides an easy possibility to log all Mails for debugging purposes. It's possible to prevent the mails to being sent, so there is no need for an extra mail server to test the mail functionality of other modules or the drupal core. Additionally you can immediately display the mail through the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) `dpm()` facility.

But you might get integration problems, since it's not easy and highly Drupal version dependent to get more than one email module at a time working.

Comment: I use the maillog module, and it seems to work well. I use with the SMTP  module though, not phpmailer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the correct phpmailer version(library) php5 or 4.

Do not use SMTP and phpmailer MODULES together.

Try to connect to localhost (port 25) first.